# What is the simplest way to rotate a pygame sprite on holding a button?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I currently have a racecar game in development, using Pygame. I understand that in order to get the sprite to move the way a real car does, trigonometry is required. However, for now, I am simply trying to get the racecar image to rotate as the user holds a button. What is the simplest way to do so?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

#DEFING COLOURS
BLACK = ( 0, 0, 0)
WHITE = ( 255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = ( 0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

size = (800,600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("My First Game")

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #BASE CAR CLASS

    def __init__(self, filename):
        #INITIALISE OBJECT PROPERTIES
        super().__init__()

        #LOAD IMAGE
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()

        #SET BACKGROUND COLOUR
        #self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

        #SET RECTANGLE COLLISION BOX
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.angle = 0
        self.angle_change = 0

#Create sprites list
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Create F1car object
F1car = Car("car.png")
car_rotation = 0.0
surface = pygame.Surface((15, 15))

#Add F1car to sprites list
all_sprites_list.add(F1car)

#LOOP UNTIL USER EXITS THE GAME
carryOn = True

#CLOCK TO CONTROL FRAME RATE
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

##MAIN LOOP##
while carryOn:
    #MAIN EVENT LOOP
    for event in pygame.event.get(): #USER DID SOMETHING
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: #IF USER CLICKED CLOSE
            carryOn = False #END THE LOOP
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                car_rotation += 0.1
                pygame.transform.rotate(surface, car_rotation)

    #GAME LOGIC

    #DRAWING CODE

    #CLEARING SCREEN
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    #DRAWING SHAPES
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [55, 200, 100, 70], 0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, [78, 300, 60, 70], 0)

    #LIST OF SPRITES TO COLLIDE WITH EACHOTHER
    #blocks_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(F1car, )

    #DRAW SPRITES FROM all_sprites_list LIST
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    #UPDATE THE SCREEN
    pygame.display.flip()

    #SET UPDATE RATE
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the `Car` class an `update` method and in this method rotate the car if `self.angle_change` is not 0. That allows you to call `all_sprites.update()` to call the `update` methods of all contained sprites.

Set the `angle_change` in the event loop to start the rotation. In the update method, increase the `self.angle` by the `self.angle_change`, then use `pygame.transform.rotate` or `.rotozoom` and pass the `self.angle`. Afterwards you need to get a new rect and pass the center of the old rect as the `center` argument.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
CAR_IMAGE = pygame.Surface((45, 90), pygame.SRCALPHA)
CAR_IMAGE.fill((150, 20, 0))


class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        # Store a reference to the original to preserve the image quality.
        self.orig_image = self.image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)

        self.angle = 0
        self.angle_change = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.angle_change != 0:
            self.angle += self.angle_change
            # I prefer rotozoom because it looks smoother.
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, self.angle, 1)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
f1_car = Car((300, 300), CAR_IMAGE)
all_sprites.add(f1_car)

carryOn = True

while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # Set the rotation speed of the car sprite.
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                f1_car.angle_change = -3
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                f1_car.angle_change = 3
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # Stop rotating if the player releases the keys.
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and f1_car.angle_change < 0:
                f1_car.angle_change = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and f1_car.angle_change > 0:
                f1_car.angle_change = 0

    all_sprites.update()

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done rather simply. You need a game loop that checks for inputs. Then you must check that the desired input is present, and increase the rotation of your car each time the input is present.

```
import pygame

run = True

car_rotation = 0.0
surface = pygame.Surface((100, 60)) # 100 horizontal length. 60 is the vertical length.

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_r:
                car_rotation += 0.1
                surface = pygame.transform.rotate(surface, car_rotation)
```

### **For the case of your code**

You have done some wrong checks in the loop. Change your code from `pygame.K_RIGHT` to `pygame.K_r`, to use your R key to rotate your sprite. In order to use the mouse, change the `pygame.event.type` to `.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `.MOUSEBUTTONUP`, and keep `pygame.K_RIGHT`.

Change the if statement, `if event.key == pygame.K_r`, to

```
if event.key == pygame.K_r
    car_rotation += 1.0
    for car in all_sprites_list:
        car.image = pygame.transform.rotate(car.image, car_rotation)
```

and then remove `surface = pygame.Surface((15, 15))`.

Comment: Don't you have to define car_rotation?

Comment: @RossC I just updated the answer to include that. I have never worked with sprites before, but I would guess Pygame Sprites are Pygame Surfaces.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: "File "H:\Computing\Project\carspinprototype2.py", line 43, in <module>
    surface = pygame.Surface()
TypeError: Required argument 'size' (pos 1) not found"

Comment: @RossC Woops. I forgot the size parameter. Check again now.

Comment: @RossC Can you post the code as part of the question?

Comment: yeah sure, see above

Comment: @RossC You must blit the car on the surface. `surface.blit(car, (x, y))`, alternatively just passing in the car: `pygame.transform.rotate(car, car_rotation)` if pygame.Sprite inherits from pygame.Surface.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155831/discussion-between-andreas-and-rossc).